# Specify "Save as image" dimensions for Word processing

Tags: r, leaflet

I have created a heatmap with leaflet, which I would like to export as image (.png) with the following dimensions:

- Length = 17.5cm
- Width = 5cm

This image will ultimately be pasted into a word document. I understand that there is the option to adjust the aspect ratio but not sure if there are alternative solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Creating a plot
x=rnorm(20)
plot(x)

# saving plot
png(file="saving_plot1.png",
    width=5, height=17.5, units="in", res=100)
hist(x, col="Black")
dev.off()
```